# Is there a WinAPI to get filename from a command line with optional spaces and other parameters?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

My goal is get a file name from a command line call/string. For instance, if I have the following strings on the input:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\mstsc.exe /v:%WKSNAME% /f
"C:\Users\User Name\Desktop\My Program.exe" /?
```

The API should return the following respectively:

```
mstsc.exe
My Program.exe
```

So I tried to use [`splitpath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7.aspx) function, and although it works for a very simple file path, it totally fails on my two examples above.

I understand that I can write my own parser (so please don't offer that.) I'm curious if there's a built-in Windows API that does it already?

PS. There must be one that OS uses internally to parse those.

PS2. Here's the code I've been toying with:

```
TCHAR buffFileName[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR buffExt[MAX_PATH];

LPCTSTR strInputPath = L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mstsc.exe /v:%WKSNAME% /f";
if(_tsplitpath_s(strInputPath, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, buffFileName, MAX_PATH, buffExt, MAX_PATH) == 0)
{
    //Got something
}
```

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: "*There must be one that OS uses internally to parse those.*" It's Windows. Why do you think there would be only one?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: He's not asking for code. He's asking if such a function exists. There's no "attempt" for him to post.

Comment: But he mentions that _splitpath didn't work.  That is hard to believe unless he is not using the function correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Updated my post with the code.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Haha. I agree, it's Windows. Still, I was thinking to try to see if there's an API in case I'll end up `reinventing the wheel`.

Comment: @c00000fd I took your code and saw no issue with usage of `_tsplitpath_s` using the string *C:\\Users\\User Name\\Desktop\\My Program.exe* (note the double slashes).  The file name is retrieved succesfully ("My Program"), as well as the extension (".exe").  [Here is a link](http://rextester.com/XYLT63352)

Comment: @c00000fd And no, don't write this yourself.  The functions are designed to properly generate the components of the file name.  If you go and code something yourself, you may miss corner cases.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes, agreed. It works for as long as you "strip out" anything else. The question is how to do it in one API. That function alone won't do it.

Comment: @c00000fd You need to clarify your question.  The functions are designed to split a file name into its components, and that's what they do and do correctly (contrary to your claim that `splitpath` "doesn't work").  I really don't know what you mean by "in one API".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: OK. Clarified it once again in the code in my OP.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think he's trying to pull the filename with a single API call. I'm somewhat at a loss if `PathFindFileName` and `splitpath` don't work as desired though.

Comment: @c00000fd Well of course what you feed `splitpath` has to be a valid file name, and `strInputPath` is not a valid file name, What you want is a command line parser, not a file name splitter.  Once you get the individual command-line components, *then* you use further functions to split the file name you got.

Comment: @c00000fd: I think your issue is in your question. It's not a "file path" if it has command line parameters. That's a completely different concept. A concept called "parsing command line parameters". You should not expect a path parsing API to be able to take a string that contains things that aren't path names. Like command lines.

Comment: @c00000fd The problem is the fact that you're trying to invoke `splitpath()` on a full command line, not just a path. What you're looking to do involves separating the program invocation from its command line arguments. You could do this yourself, but Windows provides the easy-to-use `CommandLineToArgvW()`. From there, you can use `PathStripPath()` to extract the base file name. Beware that `PathStripPath()` modifies its argument.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: Yes, I agree with what you said. (And I'll change the title for this question.) Although at times Microsoft does provide higher level APIs (usually from `Shell` dlls) that do similar stuff. For instance, [WinHttpCrackUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384092(v=vs.85).aspx) for parsing URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe [`PathFindFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be what you're looking for. From the docs:

> Searches a path for a file name.

The examples within the docs seem to show the exact behavior you describe.

---

If you'd rather parse the entire command-line, [`CommandLineToArgvW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be helpful. It takes a command-line and splits it into an array containing the filename and any arguments.

This function's parsing rules are fairly intricate, so be sure to look over the docs, but a simple explanation of them can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106050/2245528).

Comment: No, `PathFindFileName` is a very dumb API. It literally looks for anything before the last slash in a string. So for instance, for my first example, it'd return `f` :)

Comment: OK. `CommandLineToArgvW` seems to be the answer. One needs to use it first on the input string in my example (like it's shown in the code example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) and then call `PathFindFileName` on `[0]` member of the string pointer array returned by `CommandLineToArgvW`. Then it will return the needed result. Thanks. Not a single API as I was hoping... Two will work as well.